# How do I create a toggle button to subscribe and remove Fused location updates in Android?

Tags: android, locationmanager

My objective is to make a toggle button to request and remove android location updates.How can I modify this code to remove the location updates by clicking the same ImageButton?

```
 ImageButton park_search = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Park);
            park_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates( MainActivity.mGoogleApiClient, 
                    currentLocationRequest, new CurrentLocationListener(blocks) );
                }
            });


    private class CurrentLocationListener implements LocationListener {

            List<LatLng> pBlocks = new ArrayList<LatLng>();


            CurrentLocationListener(List<LatLng> blocks){
                this.pBlocks = blocks;

            }


            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                if(!MainActivity.isActive) {
                    Location endLoc = new Location("");
                    endLoc.setLongitude(pBlocks.get(0).longitude);
                    endLoc.setLatitude(pBlocks.get(0).latitude);

                    float distance = endLoc.distanceTo(location);

                    MainActivity.text_parking_info.setText("Dist = "+(int)distance);

                    if (distance < 50) {
                    //Do something
                    }
                }else{
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(MainActivity.mGoogleApiClient, this);
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a [View.setTag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) to that button (ImageButton) you can achieve this.

```
    park_search.setTag(false);//setting default as false
    park_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean status= !((boolean) view.getTag());// reverse the current status 
            if(status){
                //start location updates.
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates( MainActivity.mGoogleApiClient,currentLocationRequest, new CurrentLocationListener(blocks) )
            }else{
                //remove location updates.
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(MainActivity.mGoogleApiClient, this);
            }
            view.setTag(status);//update status 
        }
    });
```